# How to use FEniCS in Jupyter Notebook or Spyder?

Tags: python, path, anaconda

I have recently installed FEniCS using Docker with following command

```
Terminal> curl -s https://get.fenicsproject.org | bash
```

Every thing works well when I am in `fenicsproject` session. In this session when I use `which python` I get the following

```
   fenics@7016ac685f58:~$ which python
   /usr/bin/python
```

However, when I try to use the following command in Jupyter Notebook

```
from fenics import *
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-66a9e72f2de9> in <module>()
      2 # Poisson solver in Python using FEniCS
      3 # import FEniCS
----> 4 from fenics import *
      5 #
      6 # create mesh and denfine functional space

ImportError: No module named fenics
```

I am using Python provided by anaconda, details about the python are given given below

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
```

and `which python` gives me following path

```
h147:project0 vikas$ which python
/Users/vikas/anaconda/bin/python
```

I dont know how to solve this problem. Please help me.

Comment: https://github.com/conda-forge/fenics-feedstock

Comment: @cel Thank you for your reply, I did the following as per the direction given the link However, when I tried to run `from fenics import *` I get the following error 
`
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: cannot import name cpp
`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Something strange happens whenever I use fenics through Anaconda. I deactivated Anaconda and runned the fenics in the system. Worked perfectly.