# How to use FEniCS in Spyder with Python 3.8?

Tags: python, ubuntu, spyder, pde, fenics

I am quite new to python and only did smaller projects so far. For a new project I would like to use FEniCS for solving PDEs. I am working with Windows 10 and already successfully installed Ubuntu (I still do not entirely understand what Ubunutu is needed for). To test solving a PDE I executed a tutorial file "*ft01_poisson.py*" from the website of the FEniCS project (https://fenicsproject.org/tutorial/) in the Ubuntu command window and it worked.

Afterwards, I also wanted to execute the file in spyder since I will use Spyder for my own project to solve PDEs. I did `pip install fenics` and when I repeat the command it says `Requirement already satisfied: fenics c:\users\airwaves12\anaconda3\envs\spyder-4.1.5\lib\site-packages (2019.1.0)`.

But when I execute the script in spyder I always get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fenics'`. In the above-mentioned path there are only folders called `fenics_dijitso-2019.1.0.dist-info`, `fenics_ffc-2019.1.0.post0.dist-info`, `fenics_fiat-2019.1.0.dist-info`, `fenics_ufl-2019.1.0.dist-info` and `fenics-2019.1.0.dist-info`.
I know that the "fenics package" consists of different subpackages as "*ffc*", "*FIAT*", "*ufl*" or "*dijitso*". Those also excist in the above-mentioned file. I tried to manually copy those subpackages saved in folder called "fenics" into the path `C:\Users\Airwaves12\anaconda3\envs\spyder-4.1.5\Lib\site-packages` but that obviously did not work cause python did not find for example the function `UnitSquareMesh()`.

I spend almost two days reading everything concerning this topic and tried out a lot of things but the most useful advice was from [No module named 'dolfin' using Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466931/no-module-named-dolfin-using-spyder) which did not work for me and was originally just for anaconda. [How to use FEniCS in Jupyter Notebook or Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036929/how-to-use-fenics-in-jupyter-notebook-or-spyder) did not get an answer for spyder so far.

Does anyone know how to properly use FEniCS with spyder?  I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please post a small example code that generates this problem, so we can try to reproduce it in our side. That way we'll be able to understand what's happening in your case.

Comment: For example the script "ft01_poisson.py" from https://fenicsproject.org/tutorial/ which already generates an error when importing fenics.

Comment: Sorry but if you're getting an error while importing fenics, that means the problem is not directly related to Spyder and I can't help you with it.